# Copy a range of values and paste them concatenated by commas

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new on macros in Excel and I'm having a lot of troubles creating a macro that should be easy, but I don't know how to code it.
I need to copy a range of cell values (given the first cell, A2, and the last cell, Z2), but it's a dynamic range, and I need to know the last filled row to define the entire range. Then, I need to concatenate the values with commas and store that values in a .csv file.

[This is the origin template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdQ5r.png)

[This would be the resulting .csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1k2E.png)

How can I do this? I think it's not difficult, I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Find out how to save a sheet as csv file. It shouldn't be necessary to find the last row and concatenate I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me: first you define the worksheet and get the data. Then you put it into a csv row by row (with de for each loop).

In the example data in your question you already have the values separated by commas, but if you work in another language you may need the data to be separated by semicolons. In that case you should use the Replace sentence that I've left commented before the print sentence.

I hope it helps you.

```
Sub datos_a_csv()
Dim data, initial_row, final_row

'defines worksheet
Dim H_data As Worksheet
Set H_data = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Hoja1")

initial_row = 1
final_row = H_data.Cells(initial_row, 1).End(xlDown).Row + 1

'get the data
data = H_data.Cells(initial_row, 1).Resize(final_row - initial_row, 1)

'put the data in csv
My_filenumber = FreeFile

Open "C:\prueba\prueba.csv" For Append As #My_filenumber
    For Each Row In data
       'Row=replace(row,",",";")
        Print #My_filenumber, Row
    Next Row
Close #My_filenumber

End Sub
```

If you want to get the columns until the Z column, then:

```
data = H_data.Cells(initial_row, 1).Resize(final_row - initial_row, 26)
```

and then you should concatenate and store like this
'put the data in csv
    My_filenumber = FreeFile
    Open "C:\prueba\prueba.csv" For Append As #My_filenumber

```
for i = lbound(data ,1) to  ubound(data ,1) 
    row=""
    for j = lbound(data ,1) to  ubound(data ,1) 
        row = row + "," + data(i,j)
    next j
    Print #My_filenumber, Row
next i
Close #My_filenumber
```

Comment: Hi dude, thank you very much for your time. I'm getting an error in this line "row = row + "," + data(i,j)", the first time it finds a number in a cell. The format of all the cells in the Excel is "General". Do you know if I have to change the type of data or something like that? Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Sub main()
    Worksheets("toCSV").Copy '<--| change "toCSV" to your actual sheet name. this will copy the specified worksheet into the only worksheet of a new workbook
    With ActiveWorkbook '<--| refer to newly created workbook
        .SaveAs fileName:="ToCSV", FileFormat:=xlCSV '<--| this will save the new workbook with the name "ToCSV" in CSV format in the "current folder"
        .Close True 'close and save changes
    End With
End Sub
```

see [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx) for further customization of the `SaveAs()` method